# How to use reducer in createSlice without prepare function?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Hello I got the problem when I am creating reducer in createSlice, because typescript want I use prepare but I don`t need to use prepare in my reducer.
My heroesSlice

```
const heroesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'heroes',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toogleFavoriteHero: toggleStar,
    addFavoriteHeroes: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        console.log(state);
      },
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchHeroes.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const arr = action.payload.sort(
          (
            firstAbility: { primary_attr: string },
            secondAbility: { primary_attr: string }
          ) => {
            return secondAbility.primary_attr.localeCompare(
              firstAbility.primary_attr
            );
          }
        );

        state.heroes = arr;
      })
      .addCase(fetchHeroes.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.err = action.payload as string;
      });
  },
});
```

I have problem in addFavoriteHeroes -  vscode gave this warning

```
Type "{ reducer(state: WritableDraft<IHeroes>, action: PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>): void; }" cannot be assigned to type "{ reducer(state: WritableDraft<IHeroes>, action: PayloadAction <any, string, any, any>): void;} & { prepare(...a: never[]): Omit<PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>, "type">; }".
   The property "prepare" is not present in type "{ reducer(state: WritableDraft<IHeroes>, action: PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>): void; }" and is required in type "{ prepare(...a: never[]): Omit<PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>, "type">; }".
```

I found one way how to solve it, but and this way if I want to just console.log(state.heroes) i got this and I cannot use it in normal way I need to stringify it and then parse, what is uncomfortable and I am thinking should another way how use reducer in createSlice without prepare () {}

```
Proxy(Object) {i: 0, A: {…}, P: false, I: false, R: {…}, …}
```

I mean this way

```
const addHeroToFavorite: CaseReducer<typeof initialState> = (state, action) => {
  console.log(state.favoriteHeroes);
};
```

Please I would appreciate if somebody explain to me how can I create reducer in createSlice useing typescript without prepare () {}

Answer (score 0):

From the [Customizing Generated Action Creators](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) documentation:

> This object **must** contain two properties: `reducer` and `prepare`

If you don't want to specify the prepare callback, you can assign the `addHeroToFavorite` reducer function to the `reducers.addFavoriteHeroes` property directly.

```
const addHeroToFavorite: CaseReducer<typeof initialState> = (state, action) => {
    // console.log(state.favoriteHeroes);
    console.log(original(state)?.favoriteHeroes);
    return state;
};

const heroesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "heroes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addFavoriteHeroes: addHeroToFavorite,
    },
});
```

Besides, RTK uses immerjs underneath, the state is a draft state. That's why you got a proxy object.

To get the original state, you can use [`original`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#original) function.

```
import { createSlice, CaseReducer, configureStore, original } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    favoriteHeroes: [1, 2, 3],
};

const addHeroToFavorite: CaseReducer<typeof initialState> = (state, action) => {
    // console.log(state.favoriteHeroes);
    console.log(original(state)?.favoriteHeroes);
    return state;
};

const heroesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "heroes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addFavoriteHeroes: {
            reducer: addHeroToFavorite,
            prepare: (hero) => {
                return { payload: hero };
            },
        },
    },
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        heroes: heroesSlice.reducer,
    },
});

store.dispatch(heroesSlice.actions.addFavoriteHeroes(4));
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76916355-fjzz6f?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I wonder how you find answer with this original because I found only  first way to create a function and then use it like callback. Thank you again.